# React + Redux: Changing input focus programatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react application with a **'yes/no'** question interface. I'm using redux to manage state.

The app presents a series of input fields, which are added dynamically.

When a question is answered with a **'y'** or **'n'** keystroke, I want the next input in the series to get focus automatically -- enabling fast data-entry. This is proving surprisingly difficult!

My redux store contains the current question's index - I want this to translate into focus on that input.

```
/*Input Component*/
const quizQs = ({

    questionArray = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]
    currentQIndex, //From Store
    changeQIndex,  //Action

}) => {


    const _handleKeyDown = (e) => {
        if(e.key == 'y' || e.key == 'n'){
          //Dispatches Action that increases current currentQIndex'
        }
    }
    //_handleFocus()... for updating currentQIndex if an input is focused by the user


    return (
        {questionArray.map((q, index) => {

            return(
                <input
                  key={index}
                  onKeyDown={_handleKeyDown}
                  onFocus={_handleFocus}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder={q}
                  />
            )
        })}
        )
}


/*Main Component -- Connected to Store*/
class myQuiz extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
}


render(){
    return(
        <div>

            <quizQs
                currentQIndex = {this.props.currentQIndex} 
                changeQIndex = {this.props.changeQIndex}
                />
        </div>

    )}
}
```

I have tried setting `autoFocus = true`, if the store's `'currentQIndex'` matches the index of that particular question, in the `'quizQs'` component. This method is able to focus the specified field when the page first renders, but the focus does not change when the `'currentQIndex'` of the store changes.

As I have searched for an answer, React `'refs'` + use of a callback would seem to be the way to go, (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#the-ref-callback-attribute), but I cannot figure out how to set up such `'focus'` callback, that responds to changes in the Redux store.

In addition, in order to use `Refs`, the component must be set up as a class, not an arrow function. AFAIK, it is not good practice to have multiple classes in one file, and it does not seem appropriate to connect so many different components to a redux store.

I'd appreciate help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simple example of what you are trying to achieve: https://codesandbox.io/s/z64qw3nkzx

I simplified it a bit, but the point is there.

As `.focus()` is native method on the DOM element, you need a way of tracking those input elements. For that in React there is `ref` prop. It accepts a function with has one parameter which is the actual DOM element of the component.

You'll see that I put all of the DOM references into an array:

```
<input
  ref={el => this.questionInputElements[index] = el}
  key={index}
  // all other props
/>
```

and on key up* find the next element in the array and focus it:

```
const nextInput = this.questionInputElements[index + 1];

if (nextInput) {
  nextInput.focus();
}
```

* it needs to be on key up (rather than key down) as it would focus the next field before and print y/n in the next input. Try it for fun :)